# Discerning which GNU screen window is being used in a shell script

Tags: scripting, shell, gnu-screen, conditional

Using a shell script, how can you tell if a screen is running using shell scripts?

For example, using pseudocode:

```
IF (screen.screenname.running == TRUE)
```

or *something* like that.

Comment: what's your eventual goal? (I wonder if you are going to say that you want to do something which can be achived instead by screen -d -R or pgrep or ?

Comment: One way to tell the GNU screen is running is to check the `TERM` variable: if the remote server recognizes the `screen` terminal, then this will work. However, this is not a reliable indicator: one could use `vt100` just as well. (In my session, I see `TERM=screen-bce`.) However, I concur with @stew: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @David me?  just help him with his question :)

Comment: @stew: Nah: I'm asking the original poster the same question you did. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
if `screen -ls <screenname> | grep -q "There is a screen on"`; then
    echo "<screenname> is running"
fi
```